# How to find CurrentPage in MudTable

Tags: blazor

I am using MudTable of MudBlazor.
How can I read the value of currentpage of the table after using the function-event OnRowClick?

Comment: You can not ...

Answer (score 0):

In this example:

```
<MudPagination SelectedChanged="pageChanged"
                       Count="@((Products.TotalProducts + 10 - 1) / 10)" />
```

When page changes, the `pageChanged` function is called. You can call any other methods inside `pageChanged` like this:

```
    private int CurrentPage { get; set;}
private async Task pageChanged(int i)
        {
            isReLoading = true;
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            CurrentPage = i;
            await LoadProducts(CurrentPage);
        }
```

When you use `SelectedChanged`, there is no need to specify a parameter while calling the function. But in your function, you should accept an `int` as input.

I load data from server dynamically while page changes, and it also shows a loader while data is loading.